# Teamsite CMS --> XML parse error: not well-formed (invalid token) regex

Tags: regex, xml, content-management-system

I have the problem in using Teamsite CMS.
I have below code that when I generate the html file in CMS console.
It has below error. Then I google the web using string "**XML parse error: not well-formed (invalid token) regex**". But I do not find useful. Now I just comment them and can generate the html first. The worst case is to paste this code after generation but my boss needs me to fix it as he does not want to do so manually.

```
<ERROR>
XML parse error: 
not well-formed (invalid token) at line 39, column 24, byte 1955 at D:\Interwoven\TeamSite\iw-perl\vendor\lib/XML/Parser.pm line 187
</ERROR>
```

At the regex line,

```
<script>
function getParameterByName(name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
 Error this Line --->   var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if(results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you're searching for a query string parameter. In that case you should use `window.location.search` instead of `href` as it retains only the query string part. Have a look then to [https://lodash.com/docs#escapeRegExp](https://lodash.com/docs#escapeRegExp) as it seems some escaping is missing.

Comment: Actually I do not know much of the use of var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"; but I believe it we can replace it with another. it is also a solution.

Comment: Sorry I tried to read your link https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#escapeRegExp but I do not know much. Is there more simple way??

Comment: Import lodash within your page. The you'll be able to use `_.escapeRegExp()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by replacing Javascript "&" by "&".

It is able to compile and generate the result html. No Javascript error after generation and & exists in html.

```
var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
===> var regexS = "[\\?&#38;]" + name + "=([^&#38;#]*)";
```